# Change GroupBox background color in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, ios14, xcode12

How can I change the default gray background color of a GroupBox view in SwiftUI?

I tried adding a background modifier, but this just changes the white background underneath the box (see screenshot).

```
GroupBox(label: Text("Label"), content: {
    Text("Content")
})
.background(Color.blue)
```

[image: SwiftUI GroupBox screencapture with gray background and blue corners]

Comment: I don't think there is a way now but this might help you: https://www.facebook.com/349275022095690/posts/someone-asked-me-earlier-if-we-can-change-the-groupbox-background-color-in-swift/1141734002849784/

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The answer to this question has changed in recent (iOS16) versions. You can now use `backgroundStyle(_:)`. The documentation can be found [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/backgroundstyle(_:))

```
GroupBox(label: Text("Label"), content: {
    Text("Content")
})
.backgroundStyle(Color.blue)
```

Answer (score 12):

This is default group box style. You can create whatever group box needed using custom style.

Here is an example. Tested with Xcode 12 / iOS 14.

[image: demo]

```
struct DemoGroupBox: View {
    var body: some View {
        GroupBox(label: Text("Label"), content: {
             Text("Content")
        })
        .groupBoxStyle(TransparentGroupBox())
        .padding()
    }
}

struct TransparentGroupBox: GroupBoxStyle {
    func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        configuration.content
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            .padding()
            .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8).fill(Color.blue))
            .overlay(configuration.label.padding(.leading, 4), alignment: .topLeading)
    }
}
```

Comment: This is useful, but I don't think it counts as "the answer", because you have to lay out the label yourself. Add in a, "you can't" at the beginning, and then it will be the real answer.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: it is currently **not properly supported** by SwiftUI :(

Longer answer: you can create a custom `GroupBoxStyle` (see [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64282273/2993841)) which will allow you to change the background... but at the cost of having to then manually layout the contents (which somewhat defeats the purpose).

Comment: Are you saying the other two answers, which have been validated by the community, are incorrect? If so, why don't they satisfy the requirements?

Comment: @JeremyCaney I wanted to make it clear to anyone looking for the solution 'at a glance' that it is not possible to simply change the background color. The proposed 'solutions' change the background color - yes - but force you to have to set the corner radius, label layout... making it much more efficient (less lines of code) to simply make a custom component as it is really no longer a standard SwiftUI component.

Comment: Example: `VStack() { Text("Label").frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading).padding(.leading, 8) Text("Label") }.padding().background(Color.blue).cornerRadius(15)`

Comment: Please [edit] that information into your answer. "It's not possible" by itself is just a comment without an explanation.

Answer (score 3):

This problem **can be solved** in this way

*Tested on iOS 16, Xcode 14.0 Beta*

```swift
struct TestView: View {
    var body: some View {
        GroupBox(label: Text("Label"), content: {
            Text("Content")
        })
        .groupBoxStyle(ColoredGroupBox())
        .padding()
    }
}

struct ColoredGroupBox: GroupBoxStyle {
    func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                configuration.label
                    .font(.headline)
                Spacer()
            }
            
            configuration.content
        }
        .padding()
        .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8, style: .continuous)
            .fill(.blue)) // Set your color here!!
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Full code for above result

```swift
struct TestView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Divider()

            HStack {
                Text("Asperi's solution")
                Text("(Problematic with label)")
                    .bold()
            }
            
            GroupBox(label: Text("Label"), content: {
                Text("Content")
            })
            .groupBoxStyle(TransparentGroupBox())
            .padding()
            
            Divider()
            
            Text("My Solution")
            GroupBox(label: Text("Label"), content: {
                Text("Content")
            })
            .groupBoxStyle(ColoredGroupBox())
            .padding()
            
            Divider()
            
            Text("Default")
            GroupBox(label: Text("Label"), content: {
                Text("Content")
            })
            .padding()
            Divider()
        }
    }
}

struct TransparentGroupBox: GroupBoxStyle {
    func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        configuration.content
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            .padding()
            .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8).fill(Color.blue))
            .overlay(configuration.label.padding(.leading, 4), alignment: .topLeading)
    }
}

struct ColoredGroupBox: GroupBoxStyle {
    func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                configuration.label
                    .font(.headline)
                Spacer()
            }
            
            configuration.content
        }
        .padding()
        .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8, style: .continuous)
            .fill(.blue)) // Set your color here!!
    }
}
```